# Перевод с VB.NET на C#.NET

Tags: c#

Вот скажите в VB.NET я мог сделать так

```
If PictureBox1.Visible = true **and** PictureBox2.Visible = true Then
операторы
End if
```

А вот в C#.NET не пойду что вместо **and**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

должно быть - &&

Comment: Понятно, а вот скажите в VB if PictureBux1.Visible = True and PictureBox1.Visible = True Then

А вот в C# будет как?

Теперь интересует знак равно.

Comment: В С-подобных языках оператор сравнения ==

Comment: Спасибо большое проблема решена.